# Remove module install queue from OpenErp

Tags: python, postgresql, module, odoo

I was installing a custom module that requires the `decimal_precision` module, however, this module has been updated, so i downloaded and installed the brand new from `apps.openerp.com`

Now is giving me the common `No handler found` error, i need to abort the module installation queue of my openerp installation to create a new db and start over again, but it keeps giving me the error and looking for this `decimal_precision` as if i never updated it or whatever.

This is the traceback of my `openerp-server.log`

```
2013-06-08 19:27:58,544 17011 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20130206-000101
2013-06-08 19:27:58,544 17011 INFO ? openerp: addons paths:   /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons
2013-06-08 19:27:58,544 17011 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2013-06-08 19:27:58,544 17011 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2013-06-08 19:27:58,544 17011 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
2013-06-08 19:27:58,619 17011 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2013-06-08 19:27:58,619 17011 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named decimal_precision
2013-06-08 19:27:58,620 17011 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 59, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 415, in load_openerp_module
getattr(sys.modules['openerp.addons.' + module_name], info['post_load'])()
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 593, in wsgi_postload
openerp.wsgi.register_wsgi_handler(Root())
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 483, in __init__
self.load_addons()
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 546, in load_addons
m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/account/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import account
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/account/account.py", line 34, in <module>
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named decimal_precision
2013-06-08 19:27:58,624 17011 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2013-06-08 19:27:58,624 17011 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
2013-06-08 19:28:01,719 17011 INFO ? werkzeug: 200.82.128.50 - - [08/Jun/2013 19:28:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2013-06-08 19:28:02,145 17011 INFO ? werkzeug: 200.82.128.50 - - [08/Jun/2013 19:28:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

It says also that no `web` module could be found, but i think the root of the problem is still the `decimal_precision` however, the `addons` path is correct and everything else.

I dropped the installation database from `pgadmin3` stopped the server with `sudo pkill -9 -f openerp-server`
 restarted with`/etc/init.d/openerp-server start` and keeps giving me this error, even without the database installed, how can i abort all this installation without restarting the server?

(I'm logged via Teamviewer remotely, can't reboot the system cause it will kick me away until somebody logs in the server)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you reinstall the custom module or the decimal_precision module? What is the name of the custom module? sounds like that one is the culprit..

Comment: Well i substituted the decimal_precision because my custom module wasn't recognizing it, i mean, i substitute the original decimal_precision with the latest one from apps.openerp.com, but it is abnormal to me, i don't know, i mean it's the official module, just updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module http://v6apps.openerp.com/addon/655 looks like its been updated recently, perhaps they fixed a bug that caused your problems? Otherwise you might have to reinstall openerp? can you post the code for your module somewhere? Otherwise ask on http://help.openerp.com/

Comment: Of my custom module or decimal_precision one?

Comment: Oh god, i think i should re-install it :( , thank you very much anyways :)

Comment: I meant your code.. good luck though. Post if you find the solution; might help others who find this post.